# Error while starting Apache tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, spring-mvc, jdbc

My context is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/abc" >
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="50" maxIdle="15" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/abcd" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" username="***"  password="***"/>
</Context>
```

I am getting this error while starting my server.

```
Name [jdbc/abcd] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

How to solve this issue?

**Edit:**
Found the issue, My Application context is returning blank while trying to get the context by doing lookup(java:comp/env) and in my eclipse server context file i didn't  mention any configuration. It is happening because i have enabled java melody and placed 2 jars(jrobin-1.5.9.1.jar and javamelody.jar) in my tomcat lib folders. Don't know why its happening, but i found the solution that if i am putting all those application context data to eclipse  sever context file, its resolving my problem. Did anyone face this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Refer the above image and choose the option `Use Tomcat installation` now your eclipse tomcat will be pointing to the actual tomcat installation. Your Web Apps will be deployed to `wtpwebapps` folder. The default value for this **Server Locations** is `Use workspace metadata` here eclipse doest not modify the actual Tomcat Installation instead it make an instance at `yourWorkspace/servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config` which is where the eclipse context.xml you mentioned exist.

*If this option is disabled right click on the server in `servers view` select `Properties` and click `Switch Location`.Now the above options will be enabled.*

Comment: This option is always disabled for me, and in server view there is no option to switch the Location.

Comment: @Sthita Right click on the tomcat instance shown in server view choose properties and then choose Switch Location. sorry i missed properties will update the answer.

Comment: Oh ok got it.Superb.. it worked for me. Thanks a lot. Something new i have learned.